# Pulsed wave equation

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I came across the following pulsed wave plot in a paper:

[image: Pulsed wave plot]

In the paper, there is no scale as this plot is meant to visualize how a pulsed wave response would look like for ultrasound waves in soft tissues.

Now, I would like to obtain the corresponding equation in order to reproduce that plot. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where is the scale on x and y?

Comment: In the paper, there is no scale. This plot is only meant to visualize how a pulsed wave response would look like (for ultrasound waves in soft tissues for example).

Comment: You can try $y=sinc(x)$

Comment: Thank you for your response but even though sinc(x) is close, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that it might be the ultrasound response through a soft tissue.

Actually a tissue can be modelled as a continuous 3D network of spings, masses and dampers, 
which is the analog of an electrical network with distributed resistance, capacity and inductance.

Considering an input and an output point (small areas) of application and detection of the signal,
the influence of the whole body is practically limited to a small cylinder (better a [Fresnel's ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone)) around the input-output segment.

That means that we can simulate the propagation as the mechanical analogue of the
[Telegrapher's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations), or as the motion propagating along an elastic, and massive and dissipative, line.

The signal that you depicted might well be the response to a sinusoidal impulse, as in this sketch.

[image: Telegraph_eq_1]

The signal that you depicted might well be the response to a sinusoidal impulse, as in this sketch.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this very elaborate answer.

Comment: @Hagbard: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can take

$$y = e^{-ax^2}\sin(bx + c).$$

If you play around with the constants $a$, $b$ & $c$, then you'll get what you're looking for. Note - try starting with $a$ as a fraction, $b$ as 1 and $c$ will move the sine wave forwards or backwards but not the "pulse" part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to produce [the following](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+exp(0.04*x%5E2)*sin(1.0*x+%2B+2)+in+range%5B-5.5,10%5D). The only missing detail is that the plot needs to "go up" again after the second peak.

Comment: @hagbard you need to make the coefficient of x in exponential function have a minus sign infront of it. So in the case you have in the link it should be this [corrected](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+exp(-0.04*x%5E2)*sin(1.0*x+%2B+2)+in+range%5B-5.5,10%5D)

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. :)